Vexin' Markin's
Arrr, we be claimin' lands and nabbin' flags, but alas, I be goin' blind. Be ye willin' to lend a hand decipherin' the jabber o'er the horizon? Just beware the cons: piracy. I be needin' a rest now; the world be spinnin' like north be west and south be east.

(Full-resolution bucket o' pixels: https://bit.ly/ARRrrrr.)

Apologies for the low-res embedded image! If someone could point me to a way to embed a higher-resolution image, I'll do so.

The answer is

 Black Flag

because

 the flag semaphore spells out USAGE FIAV, which refers to the usage codes for each flag on the FIAV (International Federation of Vexillological Associations). The usage codes for each flag is composes of a 2x3 grid, and each grid space may be filled by a black circle. For example, the code for civil use is this (image and info source: Wikipedia, Template:FIAV)
  

we can notice that:

 These usage codes look like Braille, but sideways. After finding the usage codes for the flags (I reverse-image-searched them and used their Wikipedia pages, which have the codes listed) and flipping them sideways so they resemble Braille, then decoding, we get: BLACK FLAG.

this makes sense because:

 Pirate flags are black!


Good work, matey! ‍☠️
